# Exclude Wordpress Category from get_the_category_list

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some code that lists the category of the post you are currently on like so...

```
<?php $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'sitename' ) );
if ( $categories_list && sitename_categorized_blog() ) :?>
<span class="cat-links">
<?php printf( __( 'ALL NEWS FOR %1$s', 'sitename' ), $categories_list ); ?>
</span>
<?php endif; // End if categories ?>
```

This works great, but I just added a new ctegory called 'featured-posts'. How do I exclude this featured-posts category (either by name or ID), from appearing in the menu generated by above code?

So instead of the result...

ALL NEWS FOR: CATEGORY NAME, FEATURED POST

I just get...

ALL NEWS FOR: CATEGORY NAME

Comment: Use a custom foreach like they show in this thread http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-exclude-categories-from-get_the_category_list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

Hi, use `wp_list_categories` function instead and use 'exclude' argument.
Refer to [this codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories) for further explanations.

### Example

One place where you can put this code is inside your theme's `functions.php` file. Following you have an example:

```
function list_categories_without_this_cat() {
  $categories_stripped_of_one = wp_list_categories( array(
    'exclude' => array( 8 )
  ) );
  return $categories_stripped_of_one;
}
```

Comment: `wp_list_categories()` is for retrieving children of categories -- it does not replace the `get_the_category_list()` functionality

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using list_categories is that it lists them in a list and not as it does with get_the_category_list using commas to separate.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great answer for it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34817401/5614002

Just call get_the_category_list instead of get_the_tags_list.

I re-named the callback function exclude_cats (instead of exclude_terms), added an array of categories I wanted to skip and it was a breeze!