# wordpress exclude tag from get_the_tag_list

Tags: php, wordpress

While I use custom template tag to output single post tags:

```
<?php
echo get_the_tag_list('<p class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> ',', ','</p>');
?>
```

How to exclude defined tag name from the tag list?

Comment: You need to write custom function for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no filter to remove terms in `get_the_tag_list` but internally it calls for `get_the_terms` so you can add filter there.

Consider this example:-

```
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'exclude_terms');
echo get_the_tag_list('<p class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-tags">',', ','</i></p>');
remove_filter('get_the_terms', 'exclude_terms');
```

Add a filter on `get_the_terms` and remove it after echoing list. Because it may be called on the page multiple times.

And in callback function remove terms by IDs or slugs

```
function exclude_terms($terms) {
    $exclude_terms = array(9,11); //put term ids here to remove!
    if (!empty($terms) && is_array($terms)) {
        foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
            if (in_array($term->term_id, $exclude_terms)) {
                unset($terms[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $terms;
}
```

Comment: Using filter to exclude custom tag IDs from get_the_tag_list() was brilliant. thanks :)